# Bootstrap carousel markup error?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble initializing the Bootstrap Carousel plugin, running WordPress 3.7, trying to load in elements dynamically using a loop, but not sure what's wrong; as I understand it, I'm using the data-attributes exactly in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).  Code is below.

```
<div id="featured-things" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php foreach ($slider_things as $key => $thing): ?>
      <li data-target="#featured-things"  <?php
      if($key==0){print "class='active'";}
      ?> data-slide-to="<?php print $key?>" ></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </ol>

  <?php foreach ($slider_things as $key => $thing): ?>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item <?php
      if($key==0){print "active";}?>"  >
        <a href="<?php print $thing->url; ?>"><img src="<?=$thing->feature_image ?>" alt="<?php print $thing->title; ?>" /></a>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <p><?php print $thing->caption; ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#featured-things" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#featured-things" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

jQuery loads in header, bootstrap.min.js loads in footer.  I'm not using JS to initialize it because, as I understand it, you don't need to.

The result is that I see the slideshow, but it does not advance.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

All sorted.  Realized that I should be nesting the loop inside the .carousel-inner element.

```
<div class="carousel-inner"> 
    <?php foreach ($slider_things as $key => $thing): ?>  
        <div class="item <?php if($key==0){print "active";}?>"  >
          <a href="<?php print $thing->url; ?>">
           <img src="<?=$thing->feature_image ?>" alt="<?php print $thing->title; ?>" />
          </a>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
             <p><?php print $thing->caption; ?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Done